# Are there any tools for reviewing include or import code structure/hierarchies?

Tags: c++, include, structure, hierarchy

For example I am going through the source of some code, starting with main.cpp.

I can see that main.cpp includes "Cat.h", so I follow Cat.h and see that this header includes "Kitten.h", so I follow that, and so forth.

Essentially I want to see a tree structure of the src, so that it looks like this:

```
myProgram:
    |_ Cat.h
    |     |_ Kitten.h
    |     |_ Animal.h
    |           |_ Organism.h
    |_ Snake.h
    |      |_ Lizard.h
    |            |_ Organism.h
    |_ Etc.h
```

Comment: http://www.flourish.org/cinclude2dot/

Comment: brilliant thanks! I knew the keyword I was missing was 'dependencies'.

Comment: Your compiler should be able to do that - check the switches. `-E` and `-d<opt>` spring to mind for gcc.

Comment: Playing around with the -H and -MM flag, gave me exactly what I wanted -- thanks